# Wildcard - NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: ssl, apache2, subdomain, wildcard

I have bought wildcard certificate for **.mydomain.com**. I have another server that IP is 107.XXX.XXX.XX. I have installed apache2 and wildcard(*.mydomain.com) ssl certificate in 107.XXX.XXX.XX. when i access https://107.XXX.XXX.XX it works with exception that says **server's certificate does not match with URL**.

So i went to godaddy with my login and did forward with masking(https://sdev.mydomain.com) with https option to https://107.XXX.XXX.XX. but when i access that https://sdev.mydomain.com it says page not found. but when i access http://sdev.mydomain.com it points to http://107.XXX.XXX.XX but with address bar http://sdev.mydomain.com.

how can i make valid certificate for that https://107.XXX.XXX.XX ?

**Note** : that 107.XXX.XXX.XX is pointing to **anotherDomain.com**.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the whole point of the SSL certificate to give the user confidence that when his browser address bar shows **xyz.mydomain.com** he's actually being served by **mydomain.com** and not **abc.anotherdomain.com** ?

It seems you're trying to get your **mydomain.com** certificate accepted when a visitor goes to **anotherdomain.com**.

If you manage to get this working as described you will have broken *all* trust in *all* certificates from *all* authorities.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i make valid certificate for that https://107.XXX.XXX.XX ?

While you can do it with a private CA (which then needs to be imported as trusted into the browser) all (or at least most) public CA will no longer issue certificates for IP addresses, but only for fully qualified domain names.

Which leaves the question why do you need a certificate for the IP address at all. Commonly web sites are only accessed by hostname and not by IP address.

Comment: @MMMMS: So you want to get a certificate for an IP address which hosts a domain which is not owned by you?